# Edit document batch printing layout in SAP B1 9.2

Tags: sapb1

We are using the "Document Printing"tool from the sales to generate e-mails with invoices.

[image]

Where can I setup which print definition has to be used in batch printing?

[image]

We spend much time with a mate without success.

Answer (score 0):

Coresuite uses in batch printing all print definitions according to the ObjectId. Document Type "AR Invoices" has ObjectId 13. This corresponds to the FormType 133. 
In the print definition must be: FormType = 133, Status = Active AND Print = 'Y'.